# For sqlite, database in memory is faster than database stored on disk?

Tags: sqlite, memory

sqlite can store database file totally in memory, by using :memory: way, and it can also stores database on disk.
As I tested, insert and select speed is almost the same for in memory way and on disk way.
But I think, in memory way should be faster, for common knowledge.
Can anyone give an explain for this?

Comment: I'm not an expert in SQLite or Android, but if the database be using caching, then the "on disk" way might behave very similarly to the in memory way, at least for the queries you are running.

Answer (score -1):

In-memory db usually have the whole database in memory. (like MySQL DB Engine MEMORY) This is a huge performance boost, but RAM is expensive and often not persistent, so you would loose data on restart. There are some ways to reduce the last issue, e.g. by timed snapshots, or replication on a disk database. Also there are some hybrid types, with just a part of the db in memory.